# Fill columns with text dynamically in an already loaded table data using appendchild

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure about the title is it exactly matching my requirement sorry for the inconvenience,so all i need to do is to fill a particular column with some text and i have some what managed to fetch the data ,the only problem is it it displaying in a wrong way

In the image you can see that i have fetched the location address of the latitude and longitude on the right hand side,but the problem is it is repeated thrice and again append child has been created( I have Converted the latitude and longitude to address while loading the page,so the address is been loaded dynamically based on the latitude and longitude )

[image]

The result I expect is to be in Address column is in the line ABC I need "Vilankurichi",in DEF I need "81,G.V" and in 3rd line "2-5 Chokkampudur" and remove those duplications

My Code:
HTML:

```
       <div id="map"></div>
         <table class="table" id="zaz">
          <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Ignition</th>
            <th>Lat</th>
            <th>Long</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>7/29/2018</td>
            <td>ON</td>
            <td>11.030676</td>
            <td>77.015775</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>DEF</td>
            <td>7/29/2018</td>
            <td>OFF</td>
            <td>11.009527</td>
            <td>77.016826</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>GHI</td>
            <td>7/29/2018</td>
            <td>ON</td>
            <td>10.997547</td>
            <td>76.933858</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Javascript:

```
             var lat = '0';
    var long = '0';
    var forloopcount = 0;
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        var rowCount = document.getElementById('zaz').rows.length;
        forloopcount = (rowCount - 1);
        var table = $("table tbody");
        table.find('tr').each(function (i) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                lat = $tds.eq(4).text(),
                long = $tds.eq(5).text()
            geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
            debugger;
            function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
                var zazzzzz = lat + "," + long;
                var input = zazzzzz;
                alert(input);
                var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
                var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };
                geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status === 'OK') {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            var zazgkl = results[0].formatted_address;
                            debugger;
                            var tbody = document.getElementById('zaz').querySelectorAll('tbody tr'),
                           rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(tbody);
                            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                                var td = document.createElement('td');
                                td.textContent = zazgkl;
                                for (i = 0; i < forloopcount; i++) {
                                    row.appendChild(td);

                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

Hope I have explained the situation and waiting for any ideas and suggestion,by the way I tried using break ,return false and to terminate the for loop after appending once but is of no use in this part

```
                   rows.forEach(function (row) {
                                var td = document.createElement('td');
                                td.textContent = zazgkl;
                                for (i = 0; i < forloopcount; i++) {
                                    row.appendChild(td);

                                }
                            });
```

as I guess this part is the problem.
Waiting for any response,thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `geocodeLatLng` function as below.

```
geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, $(this)); 

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow, tr) {
    var zazzzzz = lat + "," + long;
    var input = zazzzzz;
    alert(input);
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };
    geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
                var zazgkl = results[0].formatted_address;
                debugger;
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.textContent = zazgkl;                    
                tr.appendChild(td);                                     
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What you're doing wrong is looping through all the rows again with `rows.forEach`. You don't need to do that as you already have loop with `table.find('tr').each(function (i) {`.

Comment: thanks for the effort,by trying your code I am getting console error as (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).appendChild is not a function)

Comment: @gokul updated my answer. Added new parameter in geocodeLatLng function and passed $(this) at last parameter when it’s calling

Comment: thankyou so much bro, issue is fixed only one change has been made from your code,I have replaced appendchild() with append()